# Asp.Net MVC 5 Html.DropDownList is not validating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, mvc-editor-templates

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and can't seem to find anything online that helps.

I have a Html.DropDownList in an Editor Template. I use that template in my form and don't select anything for the dropdownlist. When I click submit, I expect the form to notify me that the required dropdownlist doesn't have a value selected, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Here are the View Models:

```
public class RequestCreateViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public TesterLocationCreateViewModel TesterLocationCreateViewModel { get; set; }

    ....

    public RequestCreateViewModel()
    {

    }
}

public class TesterLocationCreateViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UIHint("OEM")]
    public string OEM { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("City")]
    public string LocationCity { get; set; }


    public TesterLocationCreateViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

Here's a snippet of the Create.cshtml

```
 @model WdcTesterManager.Models.Request

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Create Request";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 <h2>Create Request</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
       <div class="form-horizontal">
          @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
          <div class="form-group">
              @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TesterLocationCreateViewModel)
          </div>
       </div>
 }
```

Here's the TesterLocationCreateViewModel.cshtml  (Editor Template):

```
@model WdcTesterManager.Models.TesterLocationCreateViewModel

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Tester Location</h4>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OEM, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                     @Html.DropDownList("OEM", (SelectList)ViewBag.OemList, "Choose one", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OEM, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>               
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationCity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocationCity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationCity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>               
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I submit the form without filling anything out, I get a validation error for the City but nothing for the OEM. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Is you view using `TesterLocationCreateViewModel`? In which case you would need the `[Required]` attribute in that as well.

Comment: Yeah it is using that view model. I just added [Required] but it didn't help :/

Comment: Hmm - something does not makes sense because if you were using the view model without the `[UIHint]` then `EditorFor()` would never have generated a dropdownlist.

Comment: the `[UIHint]` is set in the Data Model, and it seems like it doesn't have to be set in the View Model, since it works without me setting it in the View Model. I am also confused by that...

Comment: That cannot be possible. And you getting an error message for `LocationCity` which would also be impossible since the property in the view model is not marked with `[Required]`. Something is wrong with the code you have shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for pointing that out! I took a second look at my code and realized that the Create.cshtml was using the Request model rather than the RequestCreateViewModel.  I've changed it to this, and I'm getting the correct validation errors now: `@model WdcTesterManager.Models.RequestCreateViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StephenMuecke pointed out that something looked wrong with the code, since the code seemed to be referencing the Request model rather than the Request View model.

So, I took a second look at the code and realized that the Create.cshtml was using the Request model rather than the RequestCreateViewModel.

I'm getting the correct validation errors after changing the Create.cshtml to use the RequestCreateViewModel:

```
@model WdcTesterManager.Models.RequestCreateViewModel
```