# DropDownList Required not working with ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

There are similar questions which I referred in SO but was not able to sort this out.So please don't consider as duplicate.
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806278/asp-net-mvc-5-html-dropdownlist-is-not-validating) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41512619/how-to-create-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist-with-required-validation)

ViewModel :

```
public class UserAssignRoleViewModel
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a User")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a Role")]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller ActionMethod

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string UserName, string Role)
        {
            AppUser user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            var userManager = new UserManager<AppUser>(new UserStore<AppUser>(context));

            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, Role);

            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role Assigned successfully !";


            var model = new UserAssignRoleViewModel();
            var users = context.Users.ToList();
            model.Users = users.Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.UserName,
                Text = s.UserName
            });
            var roles = context.Roles.ToList();
            model.Roles = roles.Select(s => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = s.Name,
                Text = s.Name
            });

            return View(model);
        }
```

View

```
@model ERPLite.Models.UserAssignRoleViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("RoleAddToUser", "Role"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <p>

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        User Name: @Html.DropDownListFor(u =>u.Username , (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Users, "--Select--")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Role)
        Role Name: @Html.DropDownListFor(r =>r.Role, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.Roles, "--Select-- ")

    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

The validation never fires when the button clicked. 
Appreciate any help , thanks in advance.

Comment: Your POST method needs to be `public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(UserAssignRoleViewModel model)`  if you want server side validation, and your then use `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` to check for model errors. And if you not getting client side validation, then there is a problem with your scripts.

Comment: Note also its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(u =>u.Username , Model.Users, "--Select--")` - you do not need to cast it - its already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke for the valuable inputs. If the ActionResult takes ViewModel as parameter , then how should I pass it from the dropdownlist selection. ?

Comment: Exactly as you doing now - the model in the view is `UserAssignRoleViewModel` so the parameter in your POST method should match - and its properties will be bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`. But you also need to show your scripts in the view if your not getting client side validation

Comment: These are js scripts used in the _layout file.<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="/admin-lte/js/app.min.js"></script>

Comment: For client side validation you need `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. that was the issue . thanks a lot for helping.